# Trilateration of vibration sensors - achievable resolution?

Tags: sensor, vibration

I would like to determine point of impact of 4.5mm pellet on a steel plate. In order to do so I will measure the time difference of the same impact for the 3 sensors and use trilateration.
Do you think a 5mm accuracy is achievable if I position all 3 sensors on a 100mm diameter plate?
If yes, 1mm is possible?

Subsidiary question: which sensor should I use? I would like to avoid sound as it should be used outside and maybe with other devices nearby.

They will be managed with a single ESP32

Comment: 1mm would require time resolution of the order of 150ns. I think you will have problems with reflections from the edges of the plate.

Comment: OK this is 6.5Mhz so in theory this should be possible as the esp32 is running at 240Mhz. Regarding edges, maybe adding some rubber around could help?

Comment: Making it a lot bigger should help.

Comment: OK thanks you. I will make some tests. So bigger plate but with sensors on the 100mm diameter still? Because if I move sensors to the edge I will get the same issue

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @vib I'd first collect data. Your sensor is the impact object itself. The pellet interacts with it (potentially in a complex way.) You can look at the pellet as an impulse function and the sensor sheet as something that operates on that impact to produce a result. All this can be analyzed using fourier. So study the sensor itself and its behavior. Once you understand it well you can record the resulting output, apply an inverse transform to deconvolve that back to the impulse itself. Which I suspect may be used to give you the impact position. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you @periblepsis sounds like Chinese to me but I will definitely have a look!

Comment: Neat project! It shouldn't be difficult to resolve 150ns voltage or current, but you'll have to find very fast sensors that can be bonded to sensing surface. Many sensors are designed for low-frequency signals and won't be able to resolve tiny time-of-arrival differences. So a good sensor might be something very unconventional that you construct yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will try Chinese sensors first then I will see if it fits or not